# Angularjs - ngOptions make 'group by'-group selectable

Tags: angularjs

I have this:

`<select ng-model="post" ng-options="post.manufacturer group by post.category for post in posts">`

which creates a perfectly good dropdown with manufacturers grouped on disabled categories in the browser.

I need to make the groups in the dropdown selectable. Is this possible? If so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread: [Selectable <optgroup> in HTML <select> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag)

It explains that "don't think you can" I.e, you cannot make  selectable. But you can "reproduce the visual style with css".

Sadly this probably means that the answer to this question is: no.