# Making optgroup label as selected in dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am planning to put a brief description page for the main car type (Swedish Cars). I also want to show that Volvo and Saab is under Swedish Cars in the dropdown. Then when I click on Volvo, it should navigate to the Volvo description page. How can I show the optgroup label as selected initially? 
Thank you.

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you just want the background of the `optgroup` to be highlight in some way?

Comment: optgroup is not clickable. though you can get the same effect using only option tags and css. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag

Comment: hi hungerstar. yes. i want the optgroup (which is the Swedish Cars) to be highlighted in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to have the first option being the same as the optgroup label, then hide it when the dropdown is in focus.

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
<select>
   <optgroup class="swe-car" label="Swedish Cars">
     <option value="swedish-cars">Swedish Cars</option>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   </optgroup>
</select> 
</div>

$().ready(function(){    
    $('select').focus(function(){
       $('select option').eq(0).hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atbqtnq8/13/

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking for will render like this:

[image]

This is not *strictly* possible as you can't "select" the option group label. To get the effect you're looking for you'll have to perform a bit of trickery.

We can put a custom label into a `span` and absolutely position this span over the `select` to make the initial selection **appear** as the option group label. After that we need a little bit of javascript to fake the `click` and `change` event, which you can see a working example below. However, this is what your html will look:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
 <span>Swedish Cars</span>
 <select>
  <optgroup class="swe-car" label="Swedish Cars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
 </select> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atbqtnq8/

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I copy answer from another question [Selectable <optgroup> in HTML <select> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag)

```css
.optionGroup {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
    
.optionChild {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="Swedish Cars" class="optionGroup">Swedish Cars</option>
    <option value="volvo" class="optionChild">volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" class="optionChild">saab</option>
</select>
```