# Multi-level select

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I need to do this select:

```
Object
- Children
- Children 2
-- Children
--- Test
-- Children 2
--- Test
---- Test
--- Test 2
```

[image]

I have array of objects. Each objects can be children. In these children may also be a child, etc.

@edit:

Ok, but how do the loop? I do not want to do this because the number of children in children can be unlimited:

```
                        $(myArray).each(function() {
                            if ($(this).children.length > 0) {
                                $(this).children.each(function() {
                                    if ($(this).children.length > 0) {
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Do you require the 'children' of the sub-select childs to be clickable as well?

Comment: Yes. "Children" should be clickable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9892421/3305454 This should help you.

Comment: I edited the post, look

Comment: So, what do you want? What is your expected result? If you don't want to do the loop? Do you mean that `the number of children in children can be unlimited` hierarchy length is unknown?

Comment: You need a recursive function, this should help https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/