# How to make the option group selectable?

Tags: angular

How to make the option group select able

```
<select>
   <optgroup value="0" label="Parent Tag">
      <option value="1">Child Tag</option>
      <option value="2">Child Tag</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selectable <optgroup> in HTML <select> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag)

Comment: Actual Requirement : https://www.notion.so/UX-select-dropdown-e555bae43d624275b5eaf6d766b03707

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<select multiple>
    <option value="0" label="Parent Tag"></option>
    <option value="1">Child Tag</option>
    <option value="2">Child Tag</option>
</select>
```

Choose multiple options with Ctrl+Click but it will make the only options, not dropdown.
If you want to make it dropdown use bootstrap(https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/) or Angular Material from (https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

Comment: Actual Requirement here : https://www.notion.so/UX-select-dropdown-e555bae43d624275b5eaf6d766b03707 Could you please once check.

Comment: Does it mean you are creating your list on runtime?