# How to make optgroup selectable?

Tags: angular

Can you make an optgroup selectable?

```
<mat-form-field class="h-1 text-xs w-full">
    <mat-select formControlName="source">
        <mat-option [value]="defaultSource">All</mat-option>
        <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let source of sources"
            [label]="source.source">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let subSource of source.subSources"
                [value]="{'source': source.source,'type': subSource.name}">
                {{ subSource.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to be able to select the top-level option and not just the children. Is it possible? Or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optgroup can't be made selectable. Only mat-option can be selected. But we can use a workaround by keeping all items in the select as mat-options and add some custom style to differentiate groups. You can refer the accepted answer for a similar question from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892247/selectable-optgroup-in-html-select-tag).

Or you can think of using ng-select ([link](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/grouping)), Groups can be made selectable.

Comment: Thanks. I had the idea that it cant be selectable but just wanted to see if there is a work around.