# how to declare subcategory and its inifit subcategory in laravel blade in the <select> tag

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i can get my category and its infinit sub category
but i dont know how to show them in a slect option tag in this state:
(i just want to show a subcategory (and its infinit sub category) belong to its parent in a blade)

**categories**

```
cloth
 -Men
  --Tshirt

 -Women 
  --Tshirt
```

here is my **Category Model** Method code

```
public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

here is my **migrations**

```
$table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');

            $table->foreignId('parent_id')
                  ->nullable()
                  ->constrained('categories')
                  ->cascadeOnDelete()
                  ->cascadeOnUpdate();
```

here is my **index.blade.php view**

```
<select
class="form-select @error('parent') is-ivalid @enderror"
required="">
<option selected="" value="0">None</option>
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @if($category->{'parent_id'} === null)
        <option
            value="{{$category->{'id'} }}">
            {{$category->{'title'} }}
        </option>
            @if(count($category->subcategories ))
                @include('admin.layouts.partials.subcategory' , ['sub'=>$category->subcategories])
            @endif

    @endif
@endforeach
</select>
```

here is my **partials subcategory** blade

```
@foreach($sub as $child)
    <option value="{{$child->{'id'} }}">
        {{$child->{'title'} }}
    </option>

    @if(count($child->subcategories))
        @include('admin.layouts.partials.subcategory' , ['sub'=>$child->subcategories])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: if there's a proper relations between the two you can just get all categories with subcategories. Create a foreach for categories where you define them as `<optgroup>'s` and then foreach subcategory in categories create `<option>'s` within the optgroups

Comment: my relations are good , but i will appricate if u write or correct my code specially my blade code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your relations are correct. Try changing your blade part to this:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <optgroup label={{ $category->title }}>
        @if(isset($category->subcategories))
            @foreach ($category->subcategories as $subcategories)
                <option value={{ $subcategory->id }}>
                    {{ $subcategory->title }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <option value="undefined">No available subcategories</option>
        @endif
    </optgroup>
@endforeach
```

With this you print all the categories as an option group (`optgroup`) and for every category you print it's subcategories as options within that optgroup tag. If a category has no subcategories it will display `No available subcategories`

Comment: its possible to select <optgroup ? bcz some times i need to select a <optgroup value> , your suggest <optgroup> solved my view section problem

Comment: @Abbas `optgroup` is not selectable, however there are workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460833/9636400

Comment: But you if you select an item in a subcategory, in controller you should be able to do something like `$subcategory->category` if your relationship is correct, which would ommit the need for a selectable optgroup.

Comment: tnk u i tested that but its not correctly worked for infinit sub categories :(

Comment: Define "infinit subcategories" a foreach will run aslong as there is items within the collection.

Comment: yup i able to show all subcategory but my tree structre of select option goes wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245227/discussion-between-geertjanknapen-and-abbas).